# Error building module using basic sample makefile that has always worked in the past

Tags: makefile, linux-device-driver

To add additional information to the below.  I went back to Wheezy and it worked.  I recall after the upgrade I did add `libelf` package to Jessie to get rid of the `Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install...` message.   So went back to Jessie and removed the `libelf` package and now it's building again, get that message, but it works.  Any ideas???

Updated from Wheezy to Jessie and also from 4.14.48 to 4.14.50 kernel header files, so must be in one of those two areas.  But now on a 686 Jessie build, I get an error trying to run the scripts to build a hello module for the amd64 version (the 686 version continues to build fine, and passing 'clean' build also works).
`/usr/bin/make -C std_module V=1 KDIR=/lib/modules/4.14.50-amd64-mine/build` fails with `make[3]: *** No rule to make target '/media/linux_drivers/std_module/main.o', needed by '/media/linux_drivers/std_module/hello.o'.  Stop.`

The Makefile is:

```
# this is a minimal makefile for demo purposes, keep it that way...
obj-m:=hello.o
hello-objs:=main.o
V?=0
KDIR?=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
# in an embedded system:
#KDIR:=[where the system maker gave me kernel headers+makefile or the kernel itself which has a makefile]
#ARCH:=arm
#CROSS_COMPILE:=[path+common prefix to where the toolchain is]
# You could also use W=2 and W=3 for more warnings but most kernel headers
# fail those...
W?=1
.PHONY: modules
modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(CURDIR) V=$(V) W=$(W) modules
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(CURDIR) V=$(V) clean
    rm -f *.stamp
```

Any idea on what changed or I need to fix?

Comment: Do you have a `main.c` file in the `std_module` directory?

Comment: Yes.  That package seemed to cause the problem?